# Comparing item in 2 different tables and return a value

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am comparing two tables with this sql,

```
SELECT * 
FROM TESTA 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TESTB 
                  WHERE TESTA.NAME = TESTB.NAME) 
AND TESTA.NAME = 'VALUEB'
```

and the structure of a table is

```
TESTA.NAME
----------
VALUEA
VALUEB

TESTB.NAME
----------
VALUEA
VALUEC
```

I am trying to check if the head_mark value does not exist in B. If it does not exist and it should return "NOTEXISTS" defined by OCI_DEFINE_BY_NAME().

If the head_mark exists in both tables such as VALUEA then it should return a variable "EXISTS"

please help me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Your example table structures are wrong and useless. Please give actual `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: You refer to TESTA.HEAD_MARK but the column does not occur in the sample data. Please at least supply good sample data (of all relevant columns) and the expected result.